# Upload files containing special characters with Ant SCP

Tags: ant, scp

I'd like to upload a directory with the Apache Ant `<scp>` task. This directory contains files with special characters `[ÄÖÜäöü]`.

```
<scp todir="user:password@server:/path"
  failonerror="false"
  verbose="yes"
  sftp="true"
  trust="true">
  <fileset dir="out/"/>
</scp>
```

The upload fails with:

```
[scp] Caught exception: Error sending directory 'out'
```

(How) is it possible to upload files with special characters with the Apache Ant `<scp>` task?

Comment: You mean special characters in filename?

Comment: Yes, I mean the filenames.